# How to enable fuzzy autocomplete in auto-complete and/or company-mode

Tags: company-mode, completion, auto-complete-mode, fuzzy-matching

I've searched for a long time and tried some suggestions from respective manuals like `ac-use-fuzzy` etc, but haven't been able to enable fuzzy matching. I mean I want it start without pressing any special keys.

Comment: As for `company-mode`, you could try [`company-flx`](https://github.com/PythonNut/company-flx).

Comment: @Timm Can you explain how to do that? I've tried to install flx,company-flx, but it doesn't work. Readme says that It only works with company-capf. What does that suppose to mean?

Comment: It means that for some completions (e.g. for `org-mode`) `flx` will be available, but not for all (e.g. for LaTeX/`auctex`), depending on the backend they use. Sorry, that's all I can say.